# Matlab, How to combine an adjacency matrix and two cells (one column and one row)?

Tags: matlab

I have a a matrix (74x74), a cell (1,74) of country names, and another cell (74,1) of country names. This is ideally done with matrices, but I have trouble with cells and text, I have tried horzcat and vertcat functions without success. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Plot the matrix with the text of the cells on the left and above?

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
%# matrix with row/column headers
M = rand(5,5);
rowHeader = cellstr(num2str((1:5)','Row%d')); %'
colHeader = cellstr(num2str((1:5)','Col%d')); %'

%# create cell array and fill it
C = cell(size(M)+1);
C(2:end,2:end) = num2cell(M);
C(1,2:end) = colHeader;
C(2:end,1) = rowHeader;
```

The result:

```
>> C
C = 
        []    'Col1'      'Col2'      'Col3'      'Col4'      'Col5'  
    'Row1'    [0.6207]    [0.8813]    [0.2955]    [0.6532]    [0.9243]
    'Row2'    [0.5997]    [0.0042]    [0.2491]    [0.9010]    [0.3215]
    'Row3'    [0.3355]    [0.8176]    [0.8225]    [0.9796]    [0.0500]
    'Row4'    [0.8156]    [0.3456]    [0.2515]    [0.5402]    [0.2402]
    'Row5'    [0.3910]    [0.3073]    [0.4047]    [0.0406]    [0.0734]
```